# Homestead on Chrome 62

Tags: laravel, google-chrome, homestead

I have set in my homestead yaml file my mapped url for my local machine to view my Homestead website. However it does not connect with chrome 62 but works with other browsers. Chrome 62 gives a connection refused error.
Can anyone suggest why?

Comment: What are you using as the TLD for your dev url?

Comment: Yes, that's a good question. Google has recently purchased the whole *.dev TLD, so it's possible, that Chrome 62 shows an error, because it cannot verify your test domain.

Comment: @Joe (dot)localhost

Comment: I am having this problem as well! my (dot)localhost domain

connecting to a vagrant virtualbox vm.

works fine in other browsers, but for chrome i have to specify the :8000 port

Answer (score 2):

That's because the .app and .dev domains are added to the HSTS list.
You can visit the error page, type "badidea" on your keyboard and then de site will load.